# Should I rinse cloth wipes once baby starts solids?

Tags: cloth-diaper

Once a baby starts solids, do I now need to rinse the cloth wipes? Before solids, it was only breastfed poop and the cloth wipe could just be tossed in the diaper pail. Can I still just toss it in and it will rinse out in the wash or will I need to spray it off before putting it into the washing machine?

Comment: It only takes 1 min to wash off the diaper. I'd say the risk (unlike pee, poop is NOT sterile) is not worth miniscule saving of time and effort.

Comment: When we used cloth diapers with a cleaning service (dedicated to cloth diapers), they required pre-rinsing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes ... having a 3 month old and a newly potty trained 2 and a half year old , I notticed how much eaiser the cloth diapers were with the breast fed baby.  Once they are on solids you need to rinse .

Answer (score 1):

Solid-poop diapers should have the solids eliminated before washing. You can use disposable liners (we have some bamboo fiber ones that are biodegradable), a little hose that attaches to the toilet, etc.

This is to limit the number of poop particles that remain on your clothes (and then on you).